# CSS Excel-like 'Freeze panes' where the top lines stay above the columns?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following effect: I have a large table, generated from a mysql query, and I want the top rows to stay on the page, while the body of the table scrolls vertically.
I've managed to get that working, BUT I also want the entire table to be horizontally scrollable, because part of it is off the right edge of the window.
I've been working on this for days, and I'd be grateful for some help.
Here's what I've come up with so far:
My table looks like this:

```
<div id="topLines">
  <div id="controlLine">
    <div id="testheader">
        This text is fixed!
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="resetFloat"></div>
<div id="memberTable">
    <div id="tableHeader">
        <div class="columnTitle" style="width: 100px;">Title 1</div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="width: 100px;">Title 2</div>
        <div class="columnTitle" style="width: 100px;">Title 3</div>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="columnTitle" style="width: 100px;">Title n</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resetFloat"></div>
    <div id="tableBody">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell" style="width: 100px;">Cell 1-1</div>
            <div class="tableCell" style="width: 100px;">Cell 1-2</div>
            .
            .
        </div>
        <div class="resetFloat"></div>
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell" style="width: 100px;">Cell 2-1</div>
            .
            .
        </div>
        <div class="resetFloat"></div>
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell" style="width: 100px;">Cell 3-1</div>
            .
            .
        </div>
        <div class="resetFloat"></div>
        <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="tableCell" style="width: 100px;">Cell 4-1</div>
            .
            .
        </div>
        <div class="resetFloat"></div>
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
    .resetFloat{
    clear: both;
    }

    #topLines{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

        #controlLine{
    float: left;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 50px;
    }

    #memberTable{
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 5000px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #tableHeader{
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    width: 8000px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    }

    .columnTitle{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: solid 1px white;
    height: 45px;
    }

    #tableBody{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 120px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    width: 5000px;
    }

    .tableRow{
    float: left;
    width 5000px;
    }

    .tableCell{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    border-right: solid 1px white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
margin:0}
  /* table with a fixed head*/
.table-holder {
  position:fixed;
  top:40pt;
  left:0;right:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 
}

.table-fixed-head {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.table-fixed-head th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: left;
}

/* make top lines fixed */
#topLines{
 height:40pt;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 background:#aaa;
 z-index:20
 
}
```

```html
<!--options-->
<div id="topLines">
  <div id="controlLine">
    <div id="testheader">
        This text is fixed!
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--table-->
<div class="table-holder">
  <table class="table-fixed-head">
    <thead>

      <tr>

        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Elegant and simple. I had to tweak the table-fixed-head class in order to test it: It needed "table-layout: auto;" and I added a "style='width: 200px;'" to the <th> tags, but it works just fine!

Comment: Now I need to have up to 3 header rows. when I try this, when I scroll vertically, the top 2 rows collapse and the 3rd row stays visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SwissChris, old comment I know, but to achieve this you generally need to set fixed 'top' offset values for the 2nd and 3rd rows so that they stay where you expect them to. Can be challenging if the height of the rows is variable, but can be done with a little bit of JavaScript